# Multiselect checkbox returning last result

Tags: php, html, forms, laravel

I have a form in laravel grouping together multiple checkboxes for a user to select statistics for a game. On submit, the form sends one value to the server even if no boxes were selected, which is odd.

Laravel:

```
    @for ($i = 1; $i < count($data['stats']); $i++)

         <input tabindex="1" type="checkbox" name="stats[]" id="{{ $data['stats'][$i]->Field }}" value="{{ $data['stats'][$i]->Field }}"> {{ $data['stats'][$i]->Field }}<br>

        @if ($i == 11)

            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-6">

        @endif

    @endfor

    </div>
</div>
```

Which generates this HTML:

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">


             <input tabindex="1" type="checkbox" name="stats[]" id="Prestige" value="Prestige"> Prestige<br>



             <input tabindex="1" type="checkbox" name="stats[]" id="Level" value="Level"> Level<br>



             <input tabindex="1" type="checkbox" name="stats[]" id="Experience" value="Experience"> Experience<br>



             <input tabindex="1" type="checkbox" name="stats[]" id="Points" value="Points"> Points<br>



             <input tabindex="1" type="checkbox" name="stats[]" id="Kills" value="Kills"> Kills<br>



             <input tabindex="1" type="checkbox" name="stats[]" id="Deaths" value="Deaths"> Deaths<br>



             <input tabindex="1" type="checkbox" name="stats[]" id="TeamWins" value="TeamWins"> TeamWins<br>



             <input tabindex="1" type="checkbox" name="stats[]" id="TeamLosses" value="TeamLosses"> TeamLosses<br>



             <input tabindex="1" type="checkbox" name="stats[]" id="Bonus" value="Bonus"> Bonus<br>



             <input tabindex="1" type="checkbox" name="stats[]" id="AchievementScore" value="AchievementScore"> AchievementScore<br>



             <input tabindex="1" type="checkbox" name="stats[]" id="Demented" value="Demented"> Demented<br>


                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-6">



             <input tabindex="1" type="checkbox" name="stats[]" id="Volatile" value="Volatile"> Volatile<br>



             <input tabindex="1" type="checkbox" name="stats[]" id="Undead" value="Undead"> Undead<br>



             <input tabindex="1" type="checkbox" name="stats[]" id="Scavenger" value="Scavenger"> Scavenger<br>



             <input tabindex="1" type="checkbox" name="stats[]" id="Divinity" value="Divinity"> Divinity<br>



             <input tabindex="1" type="checkbox" name="stats[]" id="Withered" value="Withered"> Withered<br>



             <input tabindex="1" type="checkbox" name="stats[]" id="Killswitch" value="Killswitch"> Killswitch<br>



             <input tabindex="1" type="checkbox" name="stats[]" id="Precise" value="Precise"> Precise<br>



             <input tabindex="1" type="checkbox" name="stats[]" id="Adept" value="Adept"> Adept<br>



             <input tabindex="1" type="checkbox" name="stats[]" id="Utility" value="Utility"> Utility<br>



             <input tabindex="1" type="checkbox" name="stats[]" id="Class" value="Class"> Class<br>



             <input tabindex="1" type="checkbox" name="stats[]" id="Perk" value="Perk"> Perk<br>



        </div>
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-block" data-after="Updated Statistics|check" style="margin-top: 6px">Update Statistics</button>

    </form>
</div>
```

On the server side:

```
if(Input::has('stats')) {

$stats = Input::get('stats');

if(is_array($stats)) {

    echo 'It is an array!';

    print_r($stats);

} else { echo 'no'; }

}
```

`$stats` always returns `Perk`, which is last on the list. Any ideas?

Comment: Scroll down, it's the last input.

Comment: This look suspicious. I suspect a framework issue. Ok, how do check? 'var_dump($_POST['stats']);' really early in the input, preferably, in 'index.php'. If ''perk' is set in 'index.php' then it is the form, if it isn't there but set later it is the 'framework'. How do you fix it? later. Checking in the 'controller' may be too late as you don't know what processing has happened by then.

Answer (score 0):

This wasn't an issue with the form itself, but the way I was submitting it. I was ajaxing the file and the data fetched from the form wasn't the most efficient way.